# Problems understanding concept of nodes and linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

i am new to Data Structures and Algorithim and i am having some troubles getting around the whole topic of linked list and how its connected to nodes. The problem that is confusing me is with pointers and what they point to

This is a sample question off a textbook

```
(i) "What happens to the pointer head when the object obj is added to an empty linked list?"
 head1 = new listNode(obj, head);
(ii) Write A Constructor to represent (i)
```

I've seen that stack overflow is the place to get some help, and i need some immediate help, all thoughts will be deeply appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you in the middle of an exam?

Comment: Why don't you describe what you do currently understand, and what you're confused by, and maybe someone will help explain something you're stuck on. But no one's going to do your homework problems for you.

Comment: its not homework, neither am i in the middle of an exam, i am looking through exam papers and textbooks as i will be facing some of this in the next coming year, so i use my time to study ahead to grab concept of what i will do next coming term, so i use past exam papers and textbooks. and i am having problems with this particular question, so you tell me if im doing homework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem that is confusing me is with pointers and what they point to?

In java *reference* works as pointer to an object in memory that internally can point to another one in the same way.

Let's try to understand it *visually*:

> What happens to the pointer head when the object obj is added to an empty linked list?

In below snapshot `head` is a reference that point to first object in the memory and first object contains another reference `next` that points to second object and so on...

[image]

> Write A Constructor to represent (i)

I think that you can do it as your homework.

Hint: (As shown in above snapshot as well)

1. create a new node
2. point `next` of new node to `next` of head
3. point `head` to new node