# Understanding linked lists (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

can someone please tell me if I am correct? I am studying for a midterm.

x is a variable pointing to a linked-list node and not the last node on the 
list. t points to a new node that is not in the list.

```
x.next = t; 
t.next = x.next;
```

I believe when it comes time to update t.next, x.next is no longer the original node following x, but is instead t itself. So it create a cycle in the list

```
t = x.next 
x = t;
```

I believe this does nothing to the list.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Insert t into the list? Do you want to insert it before x or after x?

Comment: _I believe when it comes time to update t.next, x.next is no longer the original node following x, but is instead t itself. So it create a cycle in the list_ expand it please

Comment: If that is code to insert t, then the first snippet indeed is wrong. `t.next = x.net` should be done first.

Comment: Have a look at my another post on [understanding concept of nodes and linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895790/problems-understanding-concept-of-nodes-and-linked-list/24895863#24895863)

Comment: @Eran because it is not a double-linked list, he only can insert the new node `t` after `x`.

Comment: `t = x.next; x = t;` this replaces x with t while keeping the rest of the list. So: no, it does not do "nothing" to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case store node in `temp` variable. It won't create the cycle.

```
Object temp = x.next;
x.next = t; 
t.next = temp;
```

First you have list like this..

```
X--->Y----->Z-->
```

You want to insert a node `t` after `X`

Right now `t` is

```
t---->null
```

**Step 1-**  Now we have `temp` pointing to X's next

```
x---->y----->z----->
      ^
      |
temp--
```

**Step 2-**  Now x's next is pointing to `t`

```
x----->t---->
```

now main list is like this

```
temp---->y---->z---->
```

**Step 3-**  Now t's next is pointing to temp which is only `next` pointer

```
temp---->y--->z---->
^
|
----------
          |
x---->t---
```

So resulting list is

```
x--->t---->y---->z----->
```

Comment: So in my case, if it does not create the cycle, it does nothing to the list?

Comment: "it does nothing to the list??" Can you explain more, what type of changes you are talking about with the list?

Comment: Above method will just insert the node after `x`

Comment: As far as the effect of the code fragment. For instance

Comment: It does only one thing with the list "Inserting after X node".

Comment: t.next = x.next;
x.next = t;
This would insert node t after x. 

I don't believe my code would achieve the same effect?

Comment: Yes this would also achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it threadsafe like this:

```
t.next = x.next; // let t and x point to the SAME next.
x.next = t;  // change the x.next to t(who has the old next)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have object `x`. This probably the current last element of the linked list. Now, you create a new object `T` and link it as the element after `X`

```
X    // Lets assume X.next == NULL. So linked list looks like this  X -> Null
X.next = T // Now X.next == T and T.Next == NULL, So linked list looks like this  X -> T -> Null. 
T.next = X.next // Now T.next == T. So linked list is  X -> T <->T
```

This way, when you reach the end of the linked list, it will always return the last element instead of returning `NULL`.

If you are writing a simple algorithm for this, first you have to create an element and then point its `next` variable to it self.`<First_element>.next = <First_element>`. So the logic will work for all the instances.

Here is a simple experiment.

```
class Node{
   Node next = null;
   int id =-1;
}

public class LinkedList{
   public static void main (String args[]){
      Node x = new Node();
      x.id = 0;
      x.next = x;

      // Now add a new element
      Node t = new Node();
      t.id  =1;
      x.next = t;
      t.next = x.next; // Now we have a linked list of 2 elements

      Node mynode = x;//First element of linked list
      for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
        System.out.println(mynode.id);
        mynode = mynode.next;
      }

   }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
```