# Inserting after a particular node in a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here is my complete Java source code for implementing a singly linked list. I have seen many tutorials where they have been talking about inserting a node at the beginning. So, I decided to add a method `insertAfterNode(int y)` in my code where I can add data inside a node after a particular node.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package datastructures;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Link {

    int data;

    Link next;

    public Link(int d) {

        this.data = d;
    }

    public void display() {

        System.out.println(data);
    }


    public static class LinkedList {

        Link first;

        public void insertItemFirst(int x){

            Link newLink = new Link(x);

            newLink.next = first;
            first = newLink;


        }



        public Link deleteFirst() {

            Link temp = first;
            first = first.next;
            return temp;
        }

        public void displayList() {

            Link current = first;

            while (current != null) {

                current.display();
                current = current.next;

            }

        }

        // START Of METHOD


        public void insertAfterNode(int y) {

            // Considering LinkedList is Sorted
            Link newNode = new Link(y);

            Link current = first;

            while (current != null) {

                while (current.data < y) {

                    current = current.next;
                    newNode.next = current;
                    current = newNode;

                }

            }

        }





        //END Of METHOD

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList addelements = new LinkedList();

        addelements.insertItemFirst(20);
        addelements.insertItemFirst(30);
        addelements.insertItemFirst(40);
        addelements.insertItemFirst(50);
       addelements.insertAfterNode(44);



        addelements.displayList();

        System.out.println("After Calling Deletion Method Once ");

        addelements.deleteFirst();



        addelements.displayList();

    }

}
```

The above code keeps on running in Netbeans and I had to stop the build to exit from it. I believe there is something wrong with my method implementation. Please let me know what's wrong with my following method:

```
 public void insertAfterNode(int y) {

            // Considering LinkedList is Sorted
            Link newNode = new Link(y);

            Link current = first;

            while (current != null) {

                while (current.data < y) {

                    current = current.next;
                    newNode.next = current;
                    current = newNode;

                }

            }

        }
```

The code runs just fine without above method.

Comment: Your outer `while loop` never terminates. There is no possibility for it to terminate except you enter the new node in the end. You need to redesign your logic.

Comment: In the high-level divide this problem in two parts.

1. Find out the desired node
2. Insert a new node after given node

Read more : [Problems understanding concept of nodes and linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895790/problems-understanding-concept-of-nodes-and-linked-list/24895863#24895863)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `current` Link reference changes only if the `y` value is greater than the `current.data`. If the `fist.data` is, say, 10, and the `y` is 5, your code will never terminate.

You have to modify your `while(current != null)` cycle. Do not use the inner `while`.

```
Link newNode = new Link(y);
// "first" requires a special treatment, as we need to replace the "first" value
if(first.data > y){
    // insert the new Link as first element
    newNode.next = first;
    first = newNode;
} else {
    // we need the previous Link, because previous.next will be set to the newNode
    Link previous = first;
    Link current = first.next;

    while (current != null) {
        if(current.data < y) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        } else {
            // we insert newNode between previous and current
            // btw. what should happen if current.data == y?
            previous.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = current;
            break; // we are done, quit the cycle
        }
    }
    // if the newNode.next is null at this point, means we have not inserted it yet.
    // insert it as the last element in the list. previous is pointing at it.
    if(newNode.next == null){
        previous.next = newNode;
    }
} // end of else
```

P.S. I hope it works, I have not tested the code :)