# Implement Array using linkedlist

Tags: java, arrays, list

This was asked in an interview.

Can you implement/create an object in java which is similar to `Array` class in java.

basically we should be able to iterate over the object like we do with arrays and `getValue()` or `putValue()` methods should be able to directly work on index of the object created.

ex: below operation should be performed with created object.

```
int ar[] = new int[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
     ar[i]=i;
}
```

Hint given was to use `linkedlist` data structure.
in simple words its the similar like `ArrayList` class implementation.

can anyone give me an idea how can we do this?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-use-an-array-to-implement-a-linked-list-in-Java   This might help you

Answer (score 1):

He was asking about nested objects. please read about decorator pattern. please see the below example.

```
public interface NodeInterface{

// your methods
}

public class Node implements NodeInterface{
    private NodeInterface node = null;

   // your methods

}
```

There every node contains nested object of same type. last object that have no object points to a null. you can traverse untill you find a null.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a similar question before which has been answered, and it has to do with the concept of nodes and linked list. My question can be found by following this link

[Problems understanding concept of nodes and linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895790/problems-understanding-concept-of-nodes-and-linked-list)

I accepted the answer because it helped me visualize what the linked list would look like and what my Node class would look like.

When you do make the node object, you can then make custom classes to change to value of what that node is storing, as well as retrieving and displaying the data stored in the node.

The node class would look something like this

```
public class Node{

  private int val;
  private Node node;

  public Node(int val){
      this.val=val;
  }

  public Node(Node node, int val){
      this.node = node;
      this.val = val;
  }

  public Node getNext(){
      return node;
  }

  public int getVal(){
      return val;
  }

}
```

Obviously you can modify the code to store anything you want, but this is probably what the interviewers were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Using LinkedList it should looks like:

```
LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
     linkedList.add(i);
}
```

However, I'm giving you the [link for beginners](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/linkedlist-in-java-with-example/) in which you can lear everything about the java util package. Good luck.